# Environment dismissSearch not working for macOS SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

How do I get `@Environment` to work in macOS? Here is a snippet of code below which should just be a basic NavigationView with a Search Bar in the top trailing position which should in theory trigger the text to switch between searching/not searching and when you press return it should **defocus** the searchfield and also print to console the text.

Currently, it lays out correctly but `isSearching` doesn't update and `dismissSearch()` doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""

    @Environment(\.isSearching) var isSearching
    @Environment(\.dismissSearch) var dismissSearch

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Search Bar")
            }
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(isSearching ? "Searching" : "Not Searching")
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar)
            .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                dismissSearch()
                print(searchText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, in fact, this is a perfectly workable example. All you need to do is copy paste into a new SwiftUI project or Playground and it will run. `dismissSearch` is the Environment function already provided by SwiftUI.

Comment: Ah -- gotcha! Not familiar enough with the new Swift UI 3.0 stuff yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `isSearching` & `dismissSearch` environment values are only accessible *within* a view that has the `searchable` modifier applied.

Unfortunately, it appears that `onSubmit(of: .search)` does not work within the modified view.

Your code re-arranged per Apple's `isSearching` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/issearching):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SearchableListView()
                .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar)
                .onSubmit(of: .search, someActionFunction) // appears to only work here
        }
    }

    struct SearchableListView: View {
        @Environment(\.isSearching) var isSearching
        @Environment(\.dismissSearch) var dismissSearch

        var body: some View {
            List {
                Text("Search Bar")
            }
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(isSearching ? "Searching" : "Not Searching")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get the result you want by injecting of @ObservedObject viewModel with submitAction() into SearchableListView. In this way dismissSearch() should work by .onSubmit.